# Why is my render is a completely different perspective than what I am seeing through the camera view?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera

Unfortunately I cannot share the file but here is what's up. I am rendering a car model I made. I positioned the camera to render a front 3/4 shot and it worked just fine. Next, I rotated the model 180 degrees to get a rear 3/4 shot. Once I spin the model and hit render, it just starts rendering the front 3/4 view again. I tried moving the camera around and render again, but it just applied the same camera movements but in the front 3/4 view. It's like I am working in 2 different blender files in 1 or something and it is super super confusing! Ideas?? Thank you!

Comment: Have you set any keyframes on your model or camera? Hitting ‘Render’ with re-calculate the positions using the keyframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of things happend when you hit 'Render', prior to actually rendering the frame. One of these actions is to re-evaluate any keyframes. If you have keyframes set on your camera or mesh, these will be re-positioned based on the keyframes - effectively undoing your manual positioning prior to hitting 'Render'. This is a common problem when objects unexpectedly jump back to their positions when rendering or changing frames.